# How can I run a program until the user presses ctrl+c in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script in which I require to run a binary and if I press Ctrl+c then along with script, binary which is running in background should also be stopped. I am trying this code but it does not help:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /usr/local/path-to-binary
./testBinary
read input

if (( "$input"  == "Ctrl+c")); then
ps -aef|grep Binary
pkill -9 Binary
```

Comment: I'd suggest making a habit of running code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds **before** asking questions here.

Comment: That said -- in the case of the code here, `read input` is never run until `testBinary` has exited, unless it self-daemonizes and thereby attempts to avoid detection.

Comment: ...and `(( ))` is an arithmetic construct -- it makes no sense for string comparisons, not that `read` will return the string `Ctrl+c` after being interrupted anyhow.

Comment: would you please help me to get out of this scripting problem #Charles Duffy actually I am a beginner in shell scripting..

Comment: If all you get out of this experience is code ready to copy-and-paste as an answer, then you'll have learned nothing; that's the point of the notes above, especially the first one. (I'd also suggest making note of the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and [Bash-Hackers' Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) as high-quality learning resources).

Comment: (The second comment is of interest because it raises the question of *why you think you need to do this at all*: If nothing after `./testBinary` runs until after `testBinary` has exited, then obviously, there's no reason for other parts of your script to try to run a `kill` at all; if you have a program that's partially self-daemonizing or leaving behind children, you should ask a question about that, with a reproducer, or find an existing one on the site -- we have several).

Comment: Thankyou #Charles

Answer (score 3):

There a several errors in your script. Check the [comments below your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721281/how-can-i-run-a-program-until-the-user-presses-ctrlc-in-bash#comment78400797_45721281).

Here is an example how to launch a background process and kill it on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Register signal handler for SIGINT (Ctrl+c)
trap abort INT 

function abort() {
    echo "Sending SIGINT to background process ${pid}"
    # Kill background process
    kill "${pid}"
    # Wait for it to finish after killing it
    wait "${pid}"
    # Exit the script
    echo "Aborting"
    exit 1   
}

# Start long running process in background (&)
sleep 1000 &
# Obtain the pid of that process
pid=$!
# Wait for the background process to finish
wait
```

PS: Just run the script and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. `read` is not required.